# Postgres insert with on-conflict and foreign key check

Tags: sql, postgresql

Query:

```
INSERT INTO
   derived (a, b, c)
VALUES (?, ?, ?)
ON CONFLICT (a, b, c) DO UPDATE SET
   a = EXCLUDED.a,
   b = EXCLUDED.b,
   c = EXCLUDED.c
WHERE EXISTS (select a from primary where a = ?)
```

Please note,

- fourth parameter is same as first parameter.
- derived.a has foreign-key-constraint on primary.a
- Update has to happen if there is a conflict on all 3 columns.

Unfortunately, this query is not working and I am still getting a foreign key violation when inserting with a value a which is not in primary table. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Not seeing the issue, if there is a FOREIGN KEY relationship between `derived.a` and `primary.a` and you  are  supplying a  value for `derived.a` that does not exist in `primary.a` you will get a FK error. That is the point of a FK.  The only way you can get around that is use `NULL` for the value.

Comment: Thanks @AdrianKlaver. I just don't want the insert to happen if there isn't a corresponding value in primary. 
Don't want the Foreign-key-violation to happen; require that specific insert to be ignored.

Comment: That is not going to happen per [INSERT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html): *...Note that condition is evaluated last, after a conflict has been identified as a candidate to update.*  `condition` being the `WHERE` expression. By that time the FK violation has already taken place. `ON CONFLICT` is for unique or exclusion constraints not FK ones.

Comment: So let me rephrase then.

Can there be a postgres upsert which covers both of these conditions? Insert if foreign-key constraint is matched. And. In case its an update, take care of the update.

Comment: Not with `ON CONFLICT`. You will have to test for presence of `a` first then run the insert. You could possibly use the `WITH` portion of an `INSERT` to build  a CTE that does this.

Comment: @AM01, try this
`WITH check_primary AS (
    SELECT 1 AS exists_in_primary
    FROM primary1
    WHERE a = 2  -- Replace with the value you want to insert
)
INSERT INTO derived1 (a, b, c)
SELECT 2, 'ValueB', 'ValueC'  -- Replace with your data
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM check_primary)
ON CONFLICT (a) DO UPDATE SET
    b = EXCLUDED.b,
    c = EXCLUDED.c;`

Comment: Thank you @SenthilPNathan. I tried something similar. Please have a look at the answer below.

Comment: @AM01, that's good it worked if mine was helpful you can upvote.

Comment: I did upvote :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following did what I wanted:

```
WITH data_table (a, b, c)
  AS (
    values (?, ?, ?)
  )
INSERT INTO derived (a, b, c)
SELECT dt.a, dt.b, dt.c
FROM data_table dt
WHERE EXISTS (select a from primary where a = ?)
ON CONFLICT (a, b, c) DO UPDATE SET
   a = EXCLUDED.a,
   b = EXCLUDED.b,
   c = EXCLUDED.c
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution while giving the results you want is overly complicated as it is essentially:

```
insert into
   derived (a, b, c)
values (?, ?, ?)
on conflict (a, b, c) do nothing;
```

Lets analyze your solution to see why. First off your tables must look something like:

```
create table primary_tbl (a   integer  generated always as identity
                                       primary key
                         ,name text not null
                          );

create table derived (a  integer references primary_tbl(a) 
                     ,b  integer 
                     ,c  integer
                     ,constraint derived_uk unique (a,b,c)
                     );
```

Now the actual data types and constraint types do not matter, just that `a` must be the same type in each table and must be unique in the table. Then the 3 column combination must form a unique combination in `derived`.  
Now in order to get the conflict all 3 values, in the proper order **must** already exist in `derived` so your update operation merely sets each column to the same value it already has (yes setting a column to it's current value does actually update the column). Finally, how about the `where` clause. Well if a matching value for `derived.a` did not exist in `primary.a` the row could not exist due to the it's definition as a foreign key. Thus since the data values are the same and the where must return true the row content is exactly the same. And that is what the `do nothing` clause results in. So:

```
insert into derived (a, b, c)
  values (?,?,?)
  on conflict (a, b, c) 
  do nothing;
```

The situation changes if there were another non-key column is involved (call it `d`. In this case you need to set only the value for `d` update phase, you do not need to update columns `a`,`b`,`c` - they already exit.

```
insert into derived(a,b,c,d)
  values (?,?,?,?) 
 on conflict (a,b,c) 
 do update 
       set d = excluded.d;
```

See [demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/GE4UspP9).